# Postgresql won't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed postgresql 9.5.13, but it seems not to work. I get continiosly this message:

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to    server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

when i try to create user. I have seen that this is common problem, but i can't find solution for this.

Comment: is postgres'es process running?

Comment: I don't know, how i can check it?

Comment: `ps -aef | grep postgres` and look for something with `postmaster`

Comment: No, i only got this: bozo     22936 22734  0 17:33 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres

Comment: then the process is dead you need to run postgresql

Comment: There is no version 9.5.13

Answer (score 7):

See if the service is running

```
systemctl status postgresql
```

If PostgreSQL is running, you'll see output that includes the text Active: active (exited).

If you see Active: inactive (dead), start the PostgreSQL service using the following command:

```
systemctl start postgresql
```

PostgreSQL also needs to be enabled to start on reboot. Do that with this command:

```
systemctl enable postgresql
```

Run

```
pg_lsclusters

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main 5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
Status - online - fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the server using the default database path by typing this :

```
sudo -i -u postgres

/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/ -l logfile start
```

than try:

```
psql
```

Done !

Answer (score 0):

Due to comments - you need to run the database process - take a look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html)

---

In a nutshell it should be something like

```
    postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
```

depending on what log file you want to create

Comment: What do you see in your log file?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I discovered to get this to work is to:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/postgresql
```

and then restart like in the above comments.